# MySQL replication of 2 Server with Difference DB's

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

Currently i have a cluster of server running the following (imaginary) Applications

Read_App1 , Read_App2 , Write_App1, Write_App2. The first two Apps read from MySQL and the Second two Apps as the name suggests Write to MySQL. On the DB end i have 2 Powerful X86 server with loads of RAM. My Question is how can i use this two server to Create an Effecient and Effective DB layout. The one thing comes to my mind is

DB1 <==TWO way replication==> DB2

and Write_App1 and Write_App2 write to DB1 and Read_App1 and Read_App2 read from DB2. I am using Replication to also have Data Redundancy. Is this the most efficient layout keeping in mind my requirements. Just segregating Read's and Write's. Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how up to date you need your data to be. Whether you require the additional read performance capacity of the 2 node cluster. Whether you use mult-master synchronous replication or asynchronous replication.

> Just segregating Read's and Write's

You can seperate the applications doing the writes, but the writes have to be carried out on each database in order that the data can be read.

Using asynchronous replication, DB2 will have a much higher load than DB1.